# using matplotlib to do a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

when I try to use matplotlib to plot the code i see an empty figure with no plots on it. I am attaching the code and the blank figure.  Please let me know as to what I am missing.  Thanks!

[empty window with no plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDf8p.png)

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
print(start_time)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file1 = 'fn_data.csv'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import pylab

# Read the .txt file into a dataframe
data = pd.read_csv(file1, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", header=0, delimiter=',')
rating=data.iloc[:,0]
chef=data.iloc[:,3]
print(rating)

mydict={}
i = 0
for item in chef:
    if(i>0 and item in mydict):
        continue
    else:
       i = i+1
       mydict[item] = i

chef_codes=[]
for item in chef:
    chef_codes.append(mydict[item])

print(chef_codes)
chef_codes_new=np.array(chef_codes)
rating_new=np.array(rating)
print(type(chef_codes_new),type(rating_new))
print(np.max(chef_codes_new),np.max(rating_new))
plt.plot(kind='scatter',x=chef_codes_new,y=rating_new, marker='o', ms = 10, alpha=1, color='b')
plt.axis([0, 1000, 0, 5])
plt.show()
plt.savefig("fig1.png")


end_time = datetime.now()
print(end_time)
```

Comment: Try saving the figure before showing it, for some reason this worked for me. Though I can't explain why.

Comment: Tried moving savefig before show, with the same result.  The max values are 908, 5.0  and I know that there are not many nan alues.

Comment: The figure window is empty and the .png that is saved is empty too

Comment: same results after removing the axis limits

Answer (score 0):

```
def scatterPlot(X,Y):
    ids= ['green' if y == 0 else 'red' for y in Y]
    plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], color=ids)
    plt.title("Scatter Plot")
    return

scatterPlot(x,y)
```

Its only an example of `scatter plot` hope it might help you out from your problem.

Comment: when I changed the code to plt.scatter instead of plt.plot it worked. Thanks for the suggestion. However, I still dont understand why plt.plot would not work

Answer (score 0):

If `plt.scatter` works, `plt.plot` will work as well. The problem is that you have mixed the syntax of `pandas.DataFrame.plot` with the command of `pyplot.plot`.

So, instead of

```
plt.plot(kind='scatter',x=chef_codes_new,y=rating_new, marker='o', ms = 10, alpha=1, color='b')
```

you need

```
plt.plot(chef_codes_new,rating_new, marker='o', ms = 10, alpha=1, color='b')
```

The syntax is `plt.plot(x,y, *args, **kwargs)` and you cannot use `kind="scatter"` in a pyplot plot. If you want a scatter plot, use `plt.scatter`.